# MVC3 View Update Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, modelstate

Here is a action which sets up the images to `ViewBag` for display.

```
public ActionResult UploadPhoto()
{
    List<string> images = new List<string>();

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(AlbumManager.GetAlbumName(SessionManager.CurrentSession.PropertyId, true)))
    {
        images.Add(Server.RelativePath(file));
    }

    ViewBag.Images = images;

    return PartialView("UploadPhoto");
}
```

Here is a post action which is used to delete the selected image.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string imageName)
{
    AlbumManager.DeletePhoto(SessionManager.CurrentSession.PropertyId, imageName);
    return UploadPhoto();
}
```

As you can see, once the deletion is done, I'm redirecting it to the `UploadPhoto` action which has to print the currently existing images. But after post-back the deleted image is still displaying. I'm very unsure about this behavior. Please help me to resolve this.

I tried by clearing the model state in `DeletePhoto` action with following code, but no use.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeletePhoto", "Add", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PhotoDelete" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="imageName" id="imageName" />

    <div class="thumnailsBox">
        @foreach (var image in ViewBag.Images)
        {
            <div class="thumnailTails">
                <span class="thumbimage">
                    <input id="imageSubmit" type="image" alt="No Image" src="@Url.Content(image)" /></span>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

---

### **Solution:**

In addition to [IronMan84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391762/ironman84)'s answer, here is the actual solution to my problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string imageName)
{
    AlbumManager.DeletePhoto(SessionManager.CurrentSession.PropertyId, imageName);
    return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");
}
```

I'm rendering a script to reload the page here.

Comment: Can you please post your View code? I want to see where the PartialView for UploadPhoto goes to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a PartialView in UploadPhoto, but your form is not actually targeting a DOM object to update with the result from that PartialView. I would recommend switching to `Ajax.BeginForm()`, and in your AjaxOptions including the name of the DOM object that you want to update. For more information, try looking [at this page](http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx).

Comment: Sounds great, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

You're not redirecting to the `UploadPhoto` action.

Use `RedirectToAction("UploadPhoto");` to redirect.

Also, you can try debugging the code to check if your `AlbumManager` is not caching your data or not performing the delete.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I already tried that too, but no use. Photo is deleting. If I refresh the page manually, it works fine.

Comment: Do you see the deleted image in the response? Check in FireBug. Are you properly updating the page in javascript?

Comment: I appended Guid to the image and what I could observe in the firebug is that all the images are having previous `GUID` meaning that, nothing is updated!

Comment: Well, in the response I'm getting latest result. It is definitely, some problem with the binding. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that MVC is caching your action output from the first method.  You should check the documentation for [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), You could try setting `NoStore` property, and if that didn't work, perhaps a `Duration` of 0 would prevent caching?